# Fluid - Sudden splashes during calm down

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am pouring a liquid onto a surface with the domain as boundary. Domain resolution is 300 and I am working with some viscosity. The inflow is active for 1 second and then I want the fluid to calm down and sit still. But while the liquid is calming down, I get sudden upward splashes of liquid.

Does anyone know how to prevent that?

Thanks!
Mick

Answer (score 0):

Id say rerun the bake. Fluid Dynamics are very complicated and your computer probably had some sort of Error which reslulted in a sudden net plus of Energy, thus creating the splash.
Another option may be resonance. See, the Fluid still has a lot of energy even if it is close to a resting state. And as all Dynamic systems tend to do, the Fluid kind of equalizes itself by moving. And so what can happen is that a lot of Energy suddenly gets released because a lot of Particels just happen to hit the right frequency. There is something similar that happens in the real world, but that is related to Quantum Mechanics. And Blender dosnt take those effects into account as far as i know.

Comment: I already tried multiple times with different scenes. It always happens.
Reducing the domain resolution to 200 fixed it, but it should work with higher resolutions as well.
If you want to try: create a domain with resolution 300, then activate in infill for 2 seconds and let the fluid bake for 10 seconds. You will see that after 4-5 seconds the water jumps up.